# Handling singular records of a column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database like this:

```
  ----------------------------------------------
  | ID |  Time  |    Typeop     |   Operator   |
  ----------------------------------------------
  |  1 |  10:01 |  withdrawal   |     John     |
  |  2 |  10:01 |  deposit      |     Mike     |
  |  3 |  10:01 |  deposit      |     Andrew   |
  |  4 |  10:02 |  check        |     John     |
  |  5 |  10:02 |  withdrawal   |     Simon    |
  |  6 |  10:03 |  withdrawal   |     Dorothy  |
```

by the following query i select the last three rows:

```
 SELECT * from mytable ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,3
```

THE ISSUE: I need to "echo" in a php script the last three operators in different places of my script and in different orders, so i'd assign each name to a different variable. In this example:

- $name0 = Dorothy
- $name1 = Simon
- $name3 = John

So I will be able to put them (for example) in a text like this...  "Dorothy has been the last to make an operation after Simon. John today stopped before the three..."

Thk in advance

Comment: basically what are you trying to do? why `mike` or `andrew` is not on the list since you are ordering by `id`?

Comment: what is your problem exactly ?

Comment: Yes, I'd associate to the last selected records of the field "Operator" a different variable so that i can use that values to echo in a text file. In a few words I need to handle indipendently each element of my last-3-names query of the example. Consider that I'm very newbie and maybe this is a very elementarissue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Put the result into an array and use the keys `0`, `1`, and `2` to target them:

```
$operators = array();

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Operator from mytable ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,3");

if($result)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $operators[] = $row['Operator'];
    }
}

if(count($operators) >= 3)
{
    echo htmlentities($operators[0]) . " has been the last to make an operation after " . htmlentities($operators[1]) . ". " . htmlentities($operators[2]) . " today stopped before them";
}
```

This example uses MySQLi and assumes there will always be 3 records.

**Edit:** It's the same principle when any MySQL library, for example with the native mysql_* library:

```
$operators = array();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Operator from mytable ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,3");

if($result)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $operators[] = $row['Operator'];
    }
}

if(count($operators) >= 3)
{
    echo htmlentities($operators[0]) . " has been the last to make an operation after " . htmlentities($operators[1]) . ". " . htmlentities($operators[2]) . " today stopped before them";
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and i received the following error: "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/mysite/myfile.php on line 5". The line 5 is "$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Operator from mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3");". Where do I mistake? I'm a newbie, is this MySQLi the issue? thanks for the help!

Comment: The code assumes you have created a mysqli connection object called `$mysqli`. If you haven't done that, add this at the start: `$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'databasename');` obviously change the details.

Comment: I have alredy a normal mysql connection opened in the file, is it a problem?

Comment: Furthermore consider (if this should be helpful) that I have not the server with me but i'm using a remote server, a typical website server. Bye

Comment: @mattew see my edit, I have given an example using the native mysql library.

Answer (score 0):

> // Collects data from  table

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * from mytable ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,3") or  die(mysql_error());
```

> // puts the "mytable" info into the $info array

```
 $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
```

> // print the info

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
   echo "<b>Operator:</b> ".$info['Operator'] . " "; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the result in an independent php array

```
$ops = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Operator from mytable ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,3");
$i = 0;
if($result)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))        
        $ops[$i++] = $row[0];        
}
```

Here `$row` changes each time, it will keep only latest value  but `$ops` is storing all

Now you can use this array for your desired output anywhere (until you change the array `$ops`) e.g.

```
$st = $ops[0]." has been the last to make an operation after ".$ops[1].". ".$ops[2]." today stopped before the three...";
echo $st;
```